# MySQL MATCH running very slow

Tags: mysql, match

I have a large table with about 60 million rows indexed with a fulltext index.

I am running the query below (for e.g) using Full Text search:

```
select * 
from text_file_data t 
where match( t.`description_of_goods`) against('+mobile' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
order by t.id desc
```

These queries take forever to run, sometimes more than 10 minutes. 
This is running on a AWS m3.medium server (1 vCPU, 4 GB RAM).

How can I optimize to make this run faster ?

Comment: What's the type of description_of_goods? Also what you exactly want out of this query?

Comment: description_of_goods is varchar(4096). What I'm looking for is a match of all documents having the particular search term in reverse order of occurence.

Comment: can you paste sample input and sample output.